# Create custom MKAnnotationView with xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I want to show a custom MKAnnotationView created by XIB on my map but when I load the annotation I don't see it on the map.

It's the code:

```
FPMapPin.h

#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface FPMapPin : MKAnnotationView

@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *labelText;

@end
```

---

```
FMMapPin.m

#import "FPMapPin.h"

@implementation FPMapPin

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self)
    {
        [self setup];
    }

    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self)
    {
        [self setup];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setup
{
    UIView* view = [FPCommonUtils firstViewInNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(self.class) nibOwner:self];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    view.frame = self.bounds;
    [self addSubview:view];
}
```

*NOTE: `[FPCommonUtils firstViewInNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(self.class) nibOwner:self]` simply return the view related to the xib (this method works very well)*

And this is the code related to `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` delegate method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id)annotation
{
    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([annotation class]));

        Pin *pin = (Pin*)annotation;

        FPMapPin *mapPin = [[FPMapPin alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"MapPin"];
        mapPin.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin-white"];
        mapPin.labelText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", pin.pinTag];

        return mapPin;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I have Class of Custom Annotation on MapView Class `CallOutAnnotationVifew` :

In .h File,

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface CallOutAnnotationVifew : MKAnnotationView 

@property (nonatomic,retain)UIView *contentView;
@end
```

in .m File ,

```
#import "CallOutAnnotationVifew.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


#define  Arror_height 15

@interface CallOutAnnotationVifew ()

-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context;
- (void)getDrawPath:(CGContextRef)context;
@end

@implementation CallOutAnnotationVifew
@synthesize contentView;

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.contentView = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.canShowCallout = NO;
        self.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -120);
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 220);

        UIView *_contentView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height - Arror_height)] autorelease];
        _contentView.backgroundColor   = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:_contentView];
        self.contentView = _contentView;

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Code for Adding Map View in ViewController as below.

```
self.mapView.delegate = self;
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true;
self.mapView.pitchEnabled = true;
self.mapView.showsBuildings = true;
```

Code to load Custom Annotation XIB View as below, This is Directly adding to your mapView

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    CallOutAnnotationVifew *anotationCua = [[CallOutAnnotationVifew alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CallOutAnnotationVifew"];

    NSArray *ary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Display" owner:self options:nil];

    UIView *view1 = [ary objectAtIndex:0];

    [anotationCua.contentView addSubview:view1];

    return anotationCua;
}
```

See OutPut :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

gradle solution dont work's for me, but it's part of the problem.
I change this parameter in Style files

change `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" 
        tools:ignore="NewApi">false</item>
</style>
```

Try this solution after try other solutions.
Best regards!